# Block code issue on magento 2 Product description page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, product-review

I added magento review form like this

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <container name="product.info.breviews" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product info detailed" after="-">
        <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
            <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rewards"/>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="product/view/list.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar"></block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

But its disturbing functionality of that green bar notification on product add on product description page. Is there anything wrong in code 
?

**UPDATE**

I tried to run by commenting lines issue is in this portion

```
<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
    <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rewards"/>
</block>
```

what I am doing in these 2 lines wrong ?Any help would be highly appericiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got answer issue was in this block

```
<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
    <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rewards"/>
</block>
```

As it is already defined in some place so I was redefining . I just did that

```
<move element="product.review.form" destination="content" as="review_form"  before="product.info.jbreviews" />
```

I just used now rather then again defining . moved on place where I want that and solved my problem.